# JQuery UI draggable not dropping beyond certain point scroll horizontal

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

```
function init_gearbrowser_draggables() {
    $("#gearbrowser_product_list div.product").draggable({
      start: function() {
        counts[0]++;
      },
      containment: '#sandbox_space',
      refreshPositions: true,
      helper: 'clone',
      appendTo: '#sandbox_space',
      zIndex: 12,
      delay: 200,
      scroll: false,
      scope: "sandbox_items",
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        sb_index_items();
      }

    });
  } // init_gearbrowser_draggables

// define drop space
  $('#dragspace').droppable({
    scope: "sandbox_items",
    accept: "div.product",
    tolerance: "fit",
    drop: function(event, ui) { //on drop
      //    alert("dropped");
      ui.draggable.attr("id", "sb_item");

      item_pos_top = ui.position.top;
      item_pos_left = ui.position.left;
      ui.draggable.css("top", item_pos_top);
      ui.draggable.css("left", item_pos_left);
      ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
```

Hello everyone,

I facing a (probably rather simple) glitch in a JQuery UI draggable/droppable setup.

**The below fiddle shows:**

- a left menu for new draggable divs (dog) a background droppable area
  with
- existing draggable items (red squares)
- a size of 3000 x 2000 and it's parent set to overflow:auto;

  - DOM id: #sandbox_space
  - It does scroll fine
  - has a beach background to better indicate the position while scrolling

**The problem:**

**Dragging** the dog **to the right** onto the droppable #dragspace (is #sandbox_space.ul) works fine unless
we first scroll to the right to about 75%.

Dragging the dog to the right will then result hitting an "edge".
So it is not possible to drag the dog beyond that point.
Trying to do so by scrolling 100% to the right, results in the dog
being placed on the far left.

**"containment"** and **"appendTo"** options in .draggable()
for the dog are set to #sandbox space, which is the full 3000 x 2000 px.

This only happens with a horizontal scroll past approx 75%.
It does not happen with a vertical scroll.

I understand that this is either a problem with the draggable/dropppable options
in JS or a rather stupid CSS-realted issue that I cannot figure out at this point.

Your tips are highly appreciated.
Thanks a lot !

https://jsfiddle.net/60evfLdh/12/